# Is this a bug? Changing TextBlock style at runtime in code for Windows Store Apps

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Early start to the new year on SO for me :)

I'm trying to help out a friends with what I thought would be a simple thing. Basically we just want to change a style at runtime in code and update the style for a TextBlock.

I had no problem making this work with any other type of element, except the TextBlock. I'm now very curious if I've missed something here, or if indeed there is a bug. What would be the nicest way to solve this?

The code here is just for demonstration, it works with TextBox but not TextBlock (when targettype etc is changed of course)

Style defined in a resourcedictionary called StandardStyles, under the Common folder

```
    <Style x:Key="textStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
</Style>
```

The UI

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fonts}" Height="300" Width="300" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged_1"></ListBox>
    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" Padding="20,0,0,0" Height="300" Width="300">
        <TextBlock Text="Hi here is some text" Style="{Binding FontStyleText}"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

The code

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private Style _fontStyleText;
    public Style FontStyleText
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fontStyleText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == this._fontStyleText) return;
            this._fontStyleText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private List<string> _fonts;
    public List<string> Fonts
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fonts;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == this._fonts) return;
            this._fonts = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Fonts = new List<string> {"Segoe UI", "Showcard Gothic", "Arial"};

        FontStyleText = Application.Current.Resources["textStyle"] as Style;

    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var font = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as string;

        var res = new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Common/StandardStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
        };

        var style = res["textStyle"] as Style;

        style.Setters.RemoveAt(0); // if it is the first item otherwise for more accurat removal se below :D


        foreach (var item in style.Setters.Cast<Setter>().Where(item => item.Property == FontFamilyProperty))
        {
            style.Setters.Remove(item);
        }

        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily(font)));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple)));

        FontStyleText = style;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oki, so I figured out what was wrong.

A big thank you to mlorbetske for that (and Matt on skype), I noticed something in the piece of code that I was missing. And yes, happy to say it was not a bug, but (as most of the time) something missing. Not getting an error message is a bug I would say.

I was lacking the right dependecyproperty - the target property was set wrong. So instead of:

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily(font)));
```

I had to

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily(font)));
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why it wasn't working because TextBlock is defined many times in StandardStyles.xaml. If you could create a new style document and apply that before InitilizeComponent of a User control it would work. Hope this explains.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `ListBox_SelectionChanged_1` method to read as follows.  For whatever reason there seems to have been a silent error being thrown when adding the `FontFamilyProperty` setting to the style's setters - or at least there was when I switched things around to use a separate view model.

```
    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var font = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as string;

        var res = new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Common/StandardStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
        };

        var style = res["textStyle"] as Style;
        var newStyle = new Style(style.TargetType);

        foreach (var setter in style.Setters.OfType<Setter>().Skip(1).Where(x => x.Property != TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty))
        {
            newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(setter.Property, setter.Value));
        }

        newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily(font)));
        newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple)));

        FontStyleText = newStyle;
    }
```

Comment: This does work, but how come changing the existing style wont work?

Comment: @IrisClasson for some reason, adding a setter for the `FontFamilyProperty` to the existing style after one has been removed throws a COM exception (but only after it's been done once before + I was only able to observe the behavior when I put it in a separate view model). At any rate, I'm not 100% on the why it won't work that way, but it does seem to make more sense to make a new style instead of modifying and re-assigning the same one.

Comment: Changing the same style works, I noticed when comparing your sample and mine that I was setting the wrong DP :) But tnx sooo much for this, LOL,- I can now sleep :D

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've only ever used static style bindings, never dynamic to a data context. A style is something which would normally created at design time and applied to multiple items for consistency across the app.

It might be better to have a style with everything you need except the font, have a normal static binding, then bind just the font (by name should work from memory) to override the style.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but the question is more why it doesn't work with TextBlock but with TextBlock- I'm curious if its a bug. I don't really touch the UI during runtime, but came across this issue helping somebody out. I have a hard time letting things go ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the Style of a TextBlock indeed doesn't work with bindings - you could simply update the code to put the TextBlock in a DataTemplate and add/replace the materialized instance of the template where you have your TextBlock right now when the style changes.

You could also try adding an attached property of Style type and relay its changes to the actual Style property.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I don't see a DataTrigger binding - should be under Style/Style.Triggers. You might want to try binding a trigger to your combo box - please take a look at the following links:

[Style.Triggers Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx)

[CodeProject Example on Style DataTriggers for TextBlock](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42179/WPF-DataTrigger-on-a-TextBlock)

[MSDN Question on binding a TextBlock style to a combo box change](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/904f19c6-4ee0-49fb-957b-6d828b38cf5e)

Hope it helps.

Cheers,

Arthur